# Unexpected output of for.. in loop in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, python-3.6

I wanted to run a for loop for checking every letter in a string and if `wanted` list contained the letter, then I wanted the letter to stay and if `wanted` did not contain the letter, then I wanted to remove it.

```
phrase = "Don't panic"
pList = list(phrase)
print(pList)
wanted = ["o","n","t","a","p"]
for anything in pList:
    print("Now checking", anything)
    if anything not in wanted:
        print("Removed",anything) 
        pList.remove(anything)
    elif anything in wanted:
        print("Didn't remove", anything)

print(pList)
```

The following code returns this output-

```
['D', 'o', 'n', "'", 't', ' ', 'p', 'a', 'n', 'i', 'c']                                                   

Now checking D                                                                                       
Removed D                                                                                                                                                                                           
Now checking n                                                                                          
Didn't remove n                                                                                         
Now checking '                                                                                           
Removed '                                                                                                                                                                                               
Now checking                                                                                              
Removed                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Now checking a                                                                                           
Didn't remove a                                                                                         
Now checking n                                                                                           
Didn't remove n                                                                                           
Now checking i                                                                                          
Removed i                                                                                                                                                                                       
['o', 'n', 't', 'p', 'a', 'n', 'c']
```

The code doesn't remove the last letter (i.e. "c") and letters "o", "t", "p" and "c" didn't display the `Now checking` output.

I tried removing and some lines and just ran -

```
phrase = "Don't panic"
pList = list(phrase)
print(pList)
wanted = ["o","n","t","a","p"]
for anything in pList:
    print("Now checking", anything)
```

This time the output made sense -

```
Now checking D                                                                                            
Now checking o                                                                                            
Now checking n                                                                                            
Now checking '                                                                                            
Now checking t                                                                                            
Now checking                                                                                              
Now checking p                                                                                            
Now checking a                                                                                            
Now checking n                                                                                            
Now checking i                                                                                            
Now checking c
```

So why doesn't this happen when the full code is run?

Comment: never change the list you are iterating over (`pList`)! (except you really know what you are doing).

Comment: You're editing the list as you iterate over it.

Comment: So this is probably why I encounter this error?

Comment: it certainliy is; this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: You can simply do `print([x for x in pList if x in wanted])`. Modifying the list while iterating over it might provide unexpected result. (unless we know what exactly is being done)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're editing the list as you iterate over it. Because of this, the size will change midway and you end up getting weird behaviour. You can instead create a new list to hold your filtered chars.

```
phrase = "Don't panic"
pList = list(phrase)
new_plist = []
wanted = ["o","n","t","a","p"]
for i, anything in enumerate(pList):
    print("Now checking", anything)
    if anything in wanted:
        print("Didn't remove", anything)
        new_plist.append(anything)
    else:
        print("Removed", anything)

print(new_plist)
```

A simpler way using list comprehensions is

```
pList = ''.join([i for i in pList if i not in wanted])
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers and comments are 100% correct - never modify a list while iterating over it! Something that may help with these sort of problems is thinking about the problem in the inverse: instead of *removing* from a list, invert the conditions and *add* to a new list. This way it builds up a new output based on the input rather than mutating the input = less side effects, cleaner code, functional programming principles, etc. @coldspeed's list comprehension is an elegant solution in this way.

An alternative solution with minimal changes to your original code:

```
phrase = "Don't panic"
pList = list(phrase)
print(pList)
wanted = ["o","n","t","a","p"]
finalList = []
for anything in pList:
    print("Now checking", anything)
    if anything in wanted:
        finalList.append(anything)
        print("Didn't remove", anything)
    else:
        print("Removed",anything)

print(finalList)
```

Now `pList` doesn't get modified, and the new `finalList` contains the required result. (EDIT: realized @coldspeed's code is now almost exactly the same as this - wasn't that way when I originally submitted.)